# Why can't I print a choice model instance in Django?

Tags: python, django

Just a little backstory:  I am new to Python/Django but had a working app that I had made in it that I am trying to restructure so that I can fully utilize the power of Django's Models.  I currently have a choice model that a user selects from a drop down, after that they are redirected to a success page.  Eventually, a script will execute based on their selection. On the success page I want to display their current selection as a "confirmation" of what they've executed the script on.

After researching for a good bit, I gathered sort of the direction I need to go, but am having issues implementing, which leads me to believe I may be lacking some fundamental understanding on model setup, so some clarification there would be nice.

Anyways, I want to use the get_device_display field in a template to do this.  Whenever I try to implement it, however, it does not work.  I see that some people use custom Model Managers for this, do I need to implement this somehow? Or maybe make another form/TemplateView when displaying the success page? Here is my code:

modles.py

```
from django.db import models

class DeviceChoice(models.Model):
    DEVICE_NAMES = (
    ('1', 'Haha123-9400-5'),
    ('2', 'Cisco-4506-1'),
    ('3', 'Test-3850-3'),
    ('4', 'Hello-2960C-1'),
    ('5', 'Router-9850-1'),
    ('6', 'Switch-2900-4'),
)

    device = models.CharField(max_length=20, choices=DEVICE_NAMES)
    objects = models.Manager()
```

views.py

```
def success(request):
        return render(request, 'success.html')

class SuccessView(TemplateView):
        template_name = "success.html"

class DeviceChoiceView(CreateView):
        model = DeviceChoice
        form_class = DeviceChoiceForm
        success_url = reverse_lazy('success')
        template_name = 'index.html'
```

success.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Port Reset</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <h1>Success!!</h1>
        <!--Not sure how to implement below this line-->
        {{ deviceSelection.get_device_display }}
    </body>
```

Thanks for looking. Like I said, I understand I'm missing something fundamental here about Models, but I can't seem to find out what that may be.

EDIT: Added some more code.
index.html (for submitting the deviceSelection)

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Port Reset</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <h1>Device Database</h1>
         <form action="" method="post"> 
                {% csrf_token %}
                {{ form.as_p }}
         <input type="submit" id="deviceSelection" value="Submit">
        </form>
    </body>
```

forms.py

```
from django import forms
from port_reset.models import DeviceChoice

class DeviceChoiceForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = DeviceChoice
        fields = ['device']
```

EDIT 2:

Here's what I tried doing for my views.py:

```
class SuccessView(DetailView):
        model = DeviceChoice
        template_name = "success.html"
        queryset = DeviceChoice.objects.all()

class DeviceChoiceView(CreateView):
        model = DeviceChoice
        form_class = DeviceChoiceForm
        #success_url = reverse_lazy('success')
        template_name = 'index.html'

        def get_success_url(self):
                return reverse_lazy('success', kwargs={'deviceSelection': self.deviceSelction})
```

urls.py

```
   urlpatterns = [
        path('', DeviceChoiceView.as_view(), name='index'),
        path('success/<int:deviceSelection>', SuccessView.as_view, name="success")
```

Comment: Please add more of your code, not sure where deviceSelection is coming from. If you are trying to show the device that the deviceChoice object has you should be able to user devicechoice.device in the template. But I do not think thats what you are getting add. More code will help us help you here

Comment: @TheodoreHowell  I added some more for you.  So, deviceSelection is just an ID name given to the input from the user at the form in the index template.  I was just messing around with this seeing if maybe that would get it to work, but sadly it did not.  I tried renaming to "devicechoice.device.get_device.display" But that did not work either.

Answer (score 1):

This isn't at all an issue with the choice field, or with the display method. The problem is that you don't provide any context to the template in the SuccessView; there simply is no device to display, and `deviceSelection` is undefined.

You need to use a DetailView, with a URL that contains a parameter identifying the id of the device you want to show. Then, in your create view, you need to redirect to that URL by overriding the `get_succress_url` method.

Comment: Alright, I am trying what you said.  If you see my 2nd edit above, is that on the right track? Thanks again

Comment: Yes getting there, but you should be seeing an error with this. The DetailView needs a URLpattern that includes the ID, so either you'll get an error on that, or you'll get one in the get_success_url since you don't supply an ID in the reverse call there. Also, in the SuccessView, your `get_object` method is broken since it does not actually call get_object_or_404; but note that you don't need that method at all because the DetailView will do it for you, you should remove it. Finally, you'll need to change your success.html template to `{{ object.get_device_display }}`.

Comment: Thanks again so much.  I updated my "EDIT 2" to show what changes I've made since reading your comments.  I think my one issue now is defining the ID, and passing it to the DetailView.  I tried looking at the documentation here but I'm still a little stumped.  If you think this is getting too off topic for this question, I could open another.  Documentation: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/class-based-views/generic-display/#detailview

Comment: You don't have anything called `self.deviceSelection` in your createview. You need to use `self.object.pk` in the reverse call. Similarly, your URL pattern for success needs to have `<int:pk>` so that the detailview can pick it up.